# I have a while in my do/while loop but it's still telling me I don't

Tags: c, do-while, cs50

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n=0;
    do 
        printf("Height of Pyramid:\n");
        n = GetInt();
    while (n>=0);
    printf("you picked %i", n);
}
```

and this is my error

```
mario.c:8:9: error: expected 'while' in do/while loop
        n = GetInt();
        ^
mario.c:6:5: note: to match this 'do'
    do 
    ^
```

Comment: `do { ... } while( ... );`. C doesn't use whitespace.

Comment: The syntax is `do <statement> while ( <expression> ) ;`. The `<statement>` is typically a *compound statement* or block, which includes a leading `{` and closing `}`. (You can use a single non-compound statement, but IMHO it's best to use `{` and `}` even when they're not strictly necessary -- which, in your case, they are.)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the curly brackets `{...}` . Replace with:

```
do {
    printf("Height of Pyramid:\n");
    n = GetInt();
} while (n>=0);
```